# How to prevent else-statement from being triggered everytime

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new into coding and I'm sorry to waste your time with that beginners question. I'm trying to learn JS with a eBook and my exercise atm is to write a programm which saves the entered name (first and lastname) and the entered gender. The programm should check the length of the names and give out an error if the names are too long or too short. In addition the book forces me to only accept m or f when the gender is asked. 
If everything is entered corretly it should give out something like:
"*Allright. Welcome in our society, fName lName!
Ah, we really want other (fe)males like you!*"
Only if you entered something different than m/M/f/F for your gender the else-statement should be triggered and you should read "*Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here*" (its a joke oc) But the else-statement gets always triggered. I have the same problem in different exercises so I hope I can learn from this.

```js
let firstName = prompt('Whats your first name?');
let lastName = prompt('What is your last name?');
let gender = prompt('Please type in your gender (m or w)');

if (firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12) {
  console.log(`Allright. Welcome in our society, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry. One of your names is too short/long')
}


if (gender === 'm' || gender === 'M') { 
   console.log('Ah, we really want other males like you!');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
  
if (gender === 'f' || gender === 'F') {
  console.log('Ah, we really want other females like you!');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
```

Comment: Write an else if conditional that covers the female case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have:

```
if (a) {
    // Output 1
} else {
    // Output 2
}
if (b) {
    // Output 3
} else {
    // Output 4
}
```

There's no connection between condition `a` and condition `b`, and you don't want Output 2 to occur just because `a` was false.

Instead, use `else if`:

```js
let firstName = prompt('Whats your first name?');
let lastName = prompt('What is your last name?');
let gender = prompt('Please type in your gender (m or w)');

if (firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12) {
  console.log(`Allright. Welcome in our society, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry. One of your names is too short/long')
}


if (gender === 'm' || gender === 'M') { 
  console.log('Ah, we really want other males like you!');
} else if (gender === 'f' || gender === 'F') {
  console.log('Ah, we really want other females like you!');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
```

Or you might consider `switch`:

```js
let firstName = prompt('Whats your first name?');
let lastName = prompt('What is your last name?');
let gender = prompt('Please type in your gender (m or w)');

if (firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12) {
  console.log(`Allright. Welcome in our society, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry. One of your names is too short/long')
}

switch (gender) {
  case 'm':
  case 'M':
    console.log('Ah, we really want other males like you!');
    break;
  case 'f':
  case 'F':
    console.log('Ah, we really want other females like you!');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
    break;
}
```

---

(I do strongly recommend not limiting to binary gender choices in 2019, but I assume that's a bit tangential to your question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly for me! Of course I'm not limited to binary gender choiced. I made a joke about my exercise which forced me to accept only male or female. Which way is more recommended, especially for further projects?

Comment: @Stuckz - `if`/`else if`/`else` vs. `switch` in this kind of situation is largely a matter of style. Unlike some other languages, JavaScript's `switch` really is an `if`/`else if`/`else`, not a jump table or similar. The `switch` value is evaluated, then each `case` "label" (it's really an expression) is evaluated in source code order and compared to the `switch` value, stopping at the first match. So it's really (no pun intended) a case-by-case style decision. (But when the conditions vary, rather than all just doing `==` with gender, you'd want `if`/`else if`/`else`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gender === 'm' || gender === 'M') { 
   console.log('Ah, we really want other males like you!');
} else if (gender === 'f' || gender === 'F') {
  console.log('Ah, we really want other females like you!');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

1. Do with `else if` statement while validate `gender`.And your option of gender was `m or w` but you are validate `f` instead of `w`
2. Then `first` and `last` name both are min length above 6 and you are using `&&` its only true both `first` and `last` match.
3. If you need both `first` and `last` sperate validate use with `||`.

Like this

```
(firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16) || (lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12)
```

**Snippet**

```js
let firstName = prompt('Whats your first name?');
let lastName = prompt('What is your last name?');
let gender = prompt('Please type in your gender (m or w)');

if (firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12) {
  console.log(`Allright. Welcome in our society, ${firstName} ${lastName}!`);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry. One of your names is too short/long')
}


if (gender === 'm' || gender === 'M') { 
   console.log('Ah, we really want other males like you!');
}else if(gender === 'w' || gender === 'W') {
  console.log('Ah, we really want other females like you!');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code by following steps

- Use `toLowerCase()` on gender so you need to check for only one letter.
- First you need to check if gender is `f` or `m` and then inside that `if` block you should log the message. and `else` block should log message `Sorry, we do not.....`
- Create a `Boolean` which will keep track if the first test i.e length of names is passed or not. If its not passed you should go to the `gender` checks

```js
let firstName = prompt('Whats your first name?');
let lastName = prompt('What is your last name?');
let gender = prompt('Please type in your gender (m or w)').toLowerCase();

let check = true;

if (firstName.length >= 6 && firstName.length <= 16 && lastName.length >= 3 && lastName.length <= 12) {
  check = false;
} else {
  console.log('Sorry. One of your names is too short/long')
}

if(['m','f'].some(x => x === gender) && !check){
  let str = (gender === 'm') ? 'males' : 'females';
  console.log(`As, we really want other ${str} like you`);
}
else {
  check || console.log('Sorry, we do not support gender-diversity here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to JavaScript :D

You don't have a problem with the code but with the logic.
I'll make it simple since you stated that you are new to coding:

1. You have two if clauses. Both will run.
2. If I select that I am a male person the else-if of the female check
   will run because I haven't entered f/F.
3. If I select that I am a female person the else-if of the male person
   will run because I haven't entered m/M.

=> Easiest solution: remove the else parts and add a check at the end like: **"If person hasn't entered m or M or f or F => console.log(..)"**

*PS: This is not the best solution but it's easier to understand for people who are new to coding.*